# Data Replication Without Messages

Tags: architecture, database, domain-driven-design, microservices, data-replication

We have a legacy API service and database at my workplace.

My team works on a mobile app that uses this API for some particular data. You can think of this as DDD - our service shares some entities with the legacy API service.

Besides using the legacy API, we also use a dedicated API and database for the mobile app's specific data (entities). The structure looks similar to this:

```
Mobile App -> our specific API service -> our DB (Mongo)
                      | 
                      |_________> legacy API service -> legacy DB (Postgres)
```

The problem we face is that our service performs very poorly, which results in long latency in the mobile app.

We want our service to only communicate with our DB and cut off the API calls to the legacy API.

One way would be to send the data from the legacy API service via a message broker. Unfortunately, we cannot add a message broker to the system for various reasons.

The only solution I can think of is to have a replication/caching service that would replicate the needed data by calling the legacy API service regularly (e.g., every 10 min., as it is not critical to be real-time with this data).

```
 Mobile App -> our specific API service -> our DB (Mongo)
                          ^
                          |
                  replication service (every 10 min.)
                          |
                          v 
        legacy API service -> legacy DB (Postgres)
```

To not override all the replicated data every 10 min, we can add `created_at` and `updated_at` to the legacy DB data. When we call the legacy API, we would only update our DB based on the new or newly updated data. We can make this change as it requires much less effort and time than implementing a message broker.

Though, I have not come up with an idea of how to inform our API service when a record is removed from the legacy DB.

Overall, I think this is not a very clever solution. **Is there any other way to solve the issue we are facing besides this replication/caching solution and event-driven approach?**

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The biggest constraint here is the fact that one of your systems really can't be changed much.  Event Sourcing is the design pattern that databases use to handle transaction logs and data synchronization.  It's also how version control systems work.  However, the fundamental issue is a potential need to merge events from two systems.  The events can be projected into the database.

Comment: Do you have access to the legacy system's database? Is it a SQL database? If so then you can bolt on _change data capture_ to facilitate synchronizing data to an external store that your API can access.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch thanks. Event sourcing is not an option here. And it would not solve anything without messaging anyway.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller sounds cool, I've never used CDC before, looks very promising. Thank you! The DB we use in the legacy is Postgres.

Comment: Just keep in mind that Event Sourcing != Event Messaging.  Think database transaction logs.  Not saying it's the solution here, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I know, I've built an event-sourced system before. That's not what I was asking for. Thank you anyway